# Horizontal View Pager inside a Vertical View Pager. How to pass event from Child View Pager to Parent View Pager

Tags: android, event-handling, android-viewpager

I have a Horizontal `View Pager` inside a Vertical `View Pager`. So the horizontal view pager works fine because its a child and it gets the event first. But when I do a vertical swipe on the horizontal view pager, the vertical view pager doesn't swipe (because the child consumed the event). So need to have a work around so that **I can pass the event to parent (vertical) view pager if the event is a vertical event.**

I have overridden the `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method in my `HorizontalViewPager` class:-

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) { // Check vertical and horizontal touches
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            return false;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            float upX = event.getX();
            float upY = event.getY();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaY = downY - upY;

            //HORIZONTAL SCROLL
            int min_distance = 10;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY)) {
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > min_distance) {
                    // left or right
                    if (deltaX < 0) {
                        this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaX > 0) {
                        this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    //not long enough swipe...
                    return false;
                }
            }
            //VERTICAL SCROLL
            else {
                if (Math.abs(deltaY) > min_distance) {
                    // top or down
                    if (deltaY < 0) {
                        this.onTopToBottomSwipe();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (deltaY > 0) {
                        this.onBottomToTopSwipe();
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    //not long enough swipe...
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

**parent_view_pager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainTabActivity">

    <com.android.boltt.customviews.VerticalViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

**child_view_pager.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.android.boltt.fragment.nutrition.BlankFragment">

    <com.android.boltt.customviews.CustomPagerContainer
        android:id="@+id/pager_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <com.android.boltt.customviews.HorizontalViewPager
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </com.android.boltt.customviews.CustomPagerContainer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I used [this guide](https://irpdevelop.wordpress.com/2016/02/10/horizontal-recyclerview-inside-a-vertical-recyclerview/) and it works perfectly without handling the onTouchEvent(). I hope this helps!

Comment: @MachoProgrammer: Thanks for sharing, but didn't find anything that is helpful.

Comment: Are you sure that is necessary to override the onTouchEvent()? As I wrote I implemented the same that you asked for help without touching the onTouchEvent() and it works perfectly. 
Could you please show me your xml?

Comment: @MachoProgrammer: No it's not necessary to override `onTouch` if can I have a solution without it. Editing my question.

Comment: @MachoProgrammer: I have updated the question. I just want the parent view pager to know that a vertical swipe has been performed on the child view pager

Comment: @AnasAzeem Did you get the solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sandeepmaaram, hard luck man, I didn't.